# Check if string exists in tweet using Python and Twython

Tags: python, string, twitter, comparison, twython

I receiving a stream of tweets.

I want to check each tweet and if the tweet contains the word hello I don't want to do anything but if it does not include hello I want to print it.

Can't seem to get my code working though.

```
if "hello" not in data['text'].encode('utf-8'):
        print data['text'].encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: assuming `data['text'].encode('utf-8')` is a string. then i think you want `if "hello" in data['text'].encode('utf-8'):` instead of `not in`. the way you have it, its going to print everything that DOESNT have hello in it

Comment: Yes I need to exclude tweets with the word hello in it, I think the issue is that data['text'].encode('utf-8') may not be a python or comparable string?

Comment: run `print type(data['text'].encode('utf-8'))` to find that out. are you in python3 or 2?

Comment: Yes checked it, it returns str and running 2.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working the issue was I was checking if the string was included however not taking into consideration the case of the strings, got it working using `lower()` and comparing both strings in lowercase.